# Everytime I try accessing my sharepoint site via pnp-powershell and it opens the actual site

Tags: sharepoint-server, pnp-powershell

[image]

Every time I access my sharepoint site this happens and I cant script. It works after reinstallation of the entire mangement tool. I am using the free developer site so mayb that is changing something.

Comment: What if you just close the popup? from your screenshot I can see that you are authenticated successfully. the only issue is that the window does not close. Aslo. What if you try the same steps in PowerShell ISE or simple PowerShell instead of PowerShell for SharePoint Online"?

Comment: Everything is giving me the same result

Comment: Closing the pop up will just cancel the whole thing

Comment: What if you add your SharePoint site to a Trusted zone ?

Answer (score 0):

A few things you can try:

1. Log out of your site from all browsers, then clear all browser cache and cookies.
2. Delete the cached accounts in Credential manager
3. Disabled protected mode in IE.
4. Upgrade PowerShell (to v5.1, for example).

Reference: [Connect-PnPOnline -UseWebLogin Login popup doesn't load when IE Security Level Zone is High.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63940526/connect-pnponline-useweblogin-login-popup-doesnt-load-when-ie-security-level-z)